# How to check if a point is inside a cluster of points

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry, cluster-analysis, quantization

I am asking this question for a homework on vector quantization.

I have implemented a rather classic algorithm to detect the center of a cluster of points. However in the input data there are several clusters (number of clusters and total inputs are known) and I need to find the center of each cluster but I don't know which points make a cluster. So if I manage to initialize my future center points inside or somewhere near the cluster (closer than any other initialized centers), my algorithm can iterate and go to the correct center.

However I don't know how to properly initialize. I am initializing randomly and checking if two centers are too close to each other and if a center is too far from any input point but this method isn't easy to parametrize, i.e. taking to much "computing" time or not getting the right centers.

**My idea is simple, initialize randomly and check whether the point is inside a cluster.** Someone knows how can I do that? I cannot construct a polygon since I don't know the limits of the cluster.
I would prefer an implementation in C but I take just the ideas as well!

Edit: An example of the input data:

[image: Example Data: The red points are what I should get as a result]

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <float.h>

#define TRAINING_CYCLE 10000
#define LEARNING_RATE  0.001
#define CENTROID_DISTANCE_SCALE 0.7  //used for setting a minimal distance between centroids
#define CENTROID_POINT_SCALE 0.1
#define CLUSTER_SIZE_PERCENTAGE 0.3

//User:      REMOVED
//Password:  REMOVED

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

typedef struct point{
    double x;
    double y;
} point;

int nbOfClusters;

double in1[1000];
double in2[1000];


point centers[100]; //later it is limited by number of clusters

int dataSize=0;
double maxX1, maxY1, maxX2, maxY2=0; //maximums of each data set
double deltaX, deltaY=0; //error toleration of each axis

double getAbs(double n){
    if (n>=0){
        return n;
    } else {
        return (-1)*n;
    }
}

int findNearestCentroid(point p1){ //returns the location in the table of the nearest centroid to the argument point
    double distance=DBL_MAX;
    int nearest=0;
    for (int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
        double distance_temp = (p1.x-centers[i].x)*(p1.x-centers[i].x)+(p1.y-centers[i].y)*(p1.y-centers[i].y);
        if ( distance_temp < distance){
            distance=distance_temp;
            nearest=i;
        }
    }
    return nearest;
}

double getDistance(point p1, point p2){
    return sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y));
}

bool isCentroidsNear(double minDistance){

    for (int i=0;i<nbOfClusters;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<nbOfClusters; j++){
            if (i != j){
                double temp_distance=getDistance(centers[i],centers[j]);
                if (temp_distance<minDistance){ // the distance shouldn't be small
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //if nothing hit the condition, there is no centroid too close to another
}
point findNearestInput(int centroid){ //returns the location in the table of the nearest centroid to the argument point
    double distance=DBL_MAX;
    point returnPoint;
    int nearest=0;
    for (int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
        double distance_temp = (in1[i]-centers[centroid].x)*(in1[i]-centers[centroid].x)+(in2[i]-centers[centroid].y)*(in2[i]-centers[centroid].y);
        if ( distance_temp < distance){
            distance=distance_temp;
            nearest=i;
        }
    }
    returnPoint.x=in1[nearest];
    returnPoint.y=in2[nearest];
    return returnPoint;
}

bool isPointNear(double minDistance){
    for(int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
        double distance=getDistance(findNearestInput(i),centers[i]); //the distance to the nearest point
        if(distance>minDistance){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool isCountNearPoints(double distance){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<nbOfClusters;i++){
        point p;
        for(int j=0; j<dataSize; j++){
            p.x=in1[j];
            p.y=in2[j];
            double tempDistance=getDistance(p,centers[i]);
            if (tempDistance<distance){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        //this is the number of points that the centroid should be near to
        int minNearPoints = dataSize/nbOfClusters*CLUSTER_SIZE_PERCENTAGE;
        if (counter<minNearPoints){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    char dummy[1];
    scanf("%c",&dummy[0]);
    nbOfClusters=dummy[0]-'0';



    while ( scanf("%lf,%lf", &in1[dataSize], &in2[dataSize]) != EOF){
        dataSize++;
    }


   //finding the maximums to determine the error toleration delta

    for(int i =0; i< dataSize; i++){
        if(in1[i]>0 && in1[i] > maxX1){
            maxX1=in1[i];
        }
        if(in2[i]>0 && in2[i]>maxY1){
            maxY1=in2[i];
        }
        if(in1[i]<0 && in1[i] < maxX1){
            maxX2=in1[i];
        }
        if(in2[i]<0 && in2[i] < maxY1){
            maxY2=in2[i];
        }
    }

    //double minDistance = CENTROID_DISTANCE_SCALE*sqrt((maxX1-maxX2)*(maxX1-maxX2)+(maxY1-maxY2)*(maxY1-maxY2));
    double minDistance = 1/nbOfClusters*sqrt((maxX1-maxX2)*(maxX1-maxX2)+(maxY1-maxY2)*(maxY1-maxY2));
    double pointMinDistance = CENTROID_POINT_SCALE*sqrt((maxX1-maxX2)*(maxX1-maxX2)+(maxY1-maxY2)*(maxY1-maxY2));

/*
    do { //randomly generate centroids but have finally nothing near
        for(int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
            centers[i].x=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2*(maxX1-maxX2)-(maxX1-maxX2);
            centers[i].y=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2*(maxY1-maxY2)-(maxY1-maxY2);
        }
    //} while(isCentroidsNear(minDistance) || isCountNearPoints(pointMinDistance));
    } while(isCentroidsNear(minDistance) || isPointNear(pointMinDistance));
    //} while(isCentroidsNear(minDistance));
    */
    int randomInputs[50];
    bool isSame;
    //generating nbOfClusters amount of random numbers from dataSize range that will later used to pick inputs
    do {
        do{
            //generate random numbers
            for(int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
                randomInputs[i]=(int)((double)rand()/RAND_MAX*dataSize);
            }
            isSame = false;
            //checking if the generated numbers are the same
            for(int i=0; i<nbOfClusters-1; i++){
                for(int j=i+1; j<nbOfClusters; j++){
                    if(randomInputs[i]==randomInputs[j] ){
                        isSame=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(isSame){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }while(isSame);
        //assign centroids to the generated numbers
        for (int i =0;i<nbOfClusters;i++){
            centers[i].x=in1[randomInputs[i]];
            centers[i].y=in2[randomInputs[i]];
        }
    }while(isCentroidsNear(minDistance)); //if the centroids are too close, i.e. in the same cluster
    //learning
    point p1;//point for iteration

    for (int ii=0; ii<TRAINING_CYCLE; ii++){
        for (int i=0; i<dataSize; i++){

            //construct a point
            p1.x=in1[i];
            p1.y=in2[i];

            //find the nearest point and the distance to it
            int nearPt=findNearestCentroid(p1);
            double distance=getDistance(p1,centers[nearPt]);

            //the distance that I want to move it
            double deltaDistance=LEARNING_RATE*distance;

            //moving the center on the DIRECTION of the other point
            //the slope of the line passing through both
            double slope=(in2[i]-centers[nearPt].y)/(in1[i]-centers[nearPt].x);

            double dx,dy;
            // finding how much the x needs to change => totalchange^2=dx^2+dy^2 but I know dy from dx
            dx=sqrt(deltaDistance*deltaDistance/(1+slope*slope)); //dx=(totaldist^2/(1+slope^2)


            //dx is always positive till now, so it should be neg. if the center is to the right of the point
            if(centers[nearPt].x>in1[i]){
                dx=(-1)*dx;
            }
            dy=slope*dx;
            //updating the center value
            centers[nearPt].x += dx;
            centers[nearPt].y += dy;

        }

    }

    //printing the results

    for (int i=0; i<nbOfClusters; i++){
        printf("%lf,%lf\n",centers[i].x,centers[i].y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read about K-means?

Comment: In particular, look at k-means++

Comment: There are lotsz of algorithms to split sets of points in clusters.  Your question is too broad.  can you paste your code that you made ?

Comment: I have looked at K-Means and it really did help me a lot. However the main difference is that in K-Means it seems it's up to me to split the data whereas here it's already divided

Comment: Also, **change your password**... and next time, don't share it on the web...

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to choose points from the existing data, rather than uniform random.

Since in your data model, every point belongs to a cluster, choosing existing points solves your (vague) problem, doesn't it?